# Which database is shipped with TideSDK?

Tags: tidesdk

I'm trying to use TideSDK to create a Accounting software for a client.
The software will mainly do CRUD operations.

I'm wondering which Database is shipped with TideSDK. Is it localStorage / SQLite?
Is there a way to bundle any other Database?

The reason I'm asking is, the software will store around 10 tables and each with approx 10K rows min (depends on user's plan).

What's the best way to take regular backup so we don't loose any data in case Database crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TideSDK is shipped with SQLite Database. There is no limitation for the database size for the SQLite Database, as long as you have enough harddisk space you should be able to use and expand the database.

You can certainly bundle any other database with TideSDK application. Currently the natively supported database is SQLite.